# Trying to add new row to sqlite table using Django. Getting Integrity error message

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, error-handling, django-templates

Scratching my head trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I am trying to retrieve data from an input field on my website and insert it into a sql table. When i click the submit button on my website I keep getting this error ***NOT NULL constraint failed:auctions_bid.listing_id_id***
What is causing this? any help is very much appreciated. Thanks I've attached my models.py, views.py and html pages below for additional context.

---

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.category_name}"

class Auction_listing(models.Model):
    listing = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listings")
    start_price = models.IntegerField()
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    prod_description = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bids")
    list_img = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user_id}: {self.product_name} ${self.start_price}"

class Bid(models.Model):
    bid = models.IntegerField()
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_bids")
    listing_id = models.ForeignKey(Auction_listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="all_bids")

class Comments(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_comments")
    listing_id = models.ForeignKey(Auction_listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="all_comments")
```

---

**views.py**

```
def listing(request, listing):
    #Find user id
    current_user = request.user
    new_bid = ''
    bid_count = Bid.objects.filter(listing_id=listing).count()
    #Gets the max bid for a particular listing in dictionary form
    max_bid = Bid.objects.filter(listing_id=listing).aggregate(Max('bid'))
    #Gets value of the bid__max key
    max = max_bid['bid__max']
    #Get all objects for particular listing
    page_listing = Auction_listing.objects.get(pk=listing)
    if request.method == "POST":
        bid = int(request.POST.get('Bid'))
        if bid > int(max):
            **new_bid = Bid(bid, current_user.id, listing)**
            **new_bid.save()**
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("listing"))
            #return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                #"page_listing": page_listing,
                #"Bid": bid_count,
                #"Max": max,
                #"Message": "Your bid has been reflected below"
            #})

        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
                "page_listing": page_listing,
                "Bid": bid_count,
                "Max": max,
                "Message":'Value entered must be larger than current Bid'
        })

    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/listing.html", {
            "page_listing": page_listing,
            "Bid": bid_count,
            "Max": max,
            "User": current_user
    })
```

---

**HTML Template**

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ number }}
    {{ Max }}
    {{ User }}
    <div class="">
      <h1>Listing:{{page_listing.product_name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <img src="{{page_listing.list_img.url}}" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <h3>{{ page_listing.prod_description }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <h3>{{ Bid }} bid(s) so far for this item</h3>
      {{ page_listing.start_price }}

    </div>
    <form class="" action="/listing/{{ page_listing.listing }}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="">
        <input type="text" name="Bid" value="Place bid">
      </div>
      <div class="">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Place Bid">
      </div>
    </form>



  </body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It means you did not fill in the `listing_id` field, whereas this is necessary.

Comment: You should use keyword arguments for initialising Django model instances - `Bid(bid=bid, user_id=current_user.id, listing_id=listing)`

Comment: It's convention to __not__ include "_id" in the field name for a `ForeignKey` as this is automatically added by Django as the DB column name and an attribute containing the raw value

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get my code to work by using your suggestions